# Turn off audio playing?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, avfoundation, swift4.2

I'm using `AVPlayer` to play audio from a `URL`. Everything works fine, but I don't know how to stop current Audio playing when I am in a different `ViewController` I don't want to call `player.pause()` in `viewWillDisappear()` because i want to stop it in specific cases, but I want still to play the audio in the background when the app is inactive.

I have this turned on in Xcode app settings for background playback when the app is inactive[image]

> > 2nd question: Can I improve this class or is everything ok?

```
protocol AVPlayerServiceDelegate {
    func playerDidUpdateCurrentPlayingTime(_ time: CMTime)

}

class AVPlayerService {
    static let instance = AVPlayerService()

    private var audioPlayer: AVPlayer!
    public weak var delegate: AVPlayerServiceDelegate?

    func setupPlayer(forURL url: URL) {
        let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        audioPlayer.play()

        audioPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
            if self.audioPlayer.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                self.delegate?.playerDidUpdateCurrentPlayingTime(self.audioPlayer.currentTime())
            }
        }
    }

    var isPlaying: Bool {
        return audioPlayer.isPlaying
    }

    var isPaused: Bool {
        return audioPlayer.isPaused
    }

    var rate: Float {
        return audioPlayer.rate
    }

    func seek(to time: CMTime) {
        audioPlayer.seek(to: time)
    }

    func seekToBeginning() {
        audioPlayer.seek(to: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1))
    }

    func replay() {
        audioPlayer.seek(to: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1))
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    func pause() {
        if let audioPlayer = audioPlayer {
            audioPlayer.pause()
        }
    }

    func play() {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    func freshInstance() {
        audioPlayer = AVPlayer()
    }

    var assetDuration: CMTime {
        get {
            return audioPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mechanism to talk to the `player` object in order to perform actions on it.
There are many ways to go about it.

Personally, I would create a dedicated class for the player that deals with instantiating it, loading the audio resource, playing, pausing, etc.
Then I would either have this class be a singleton so I can access it from anywhere, or inject it and pass it onto other classes where it will be used.

#### Basic Example:

```
class MyAudioPlayer {
    static let shared = MyAudioPlayer()
    
    private var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    func load(_ url: URL) {
        player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    }

    func play(url: URL) {
        load(url: url)
        player?.play()
    }

    func pause() {
        player?.pause()
    }

    func stop() {
        player?.stop()
    }     
}
```

---

Send actions from anywhere within app:

```
MyAudioPlayer.shared.play(someURL)
MyAudioPlayer.shared.pause()
```

---

As for playing in background even when app is not active will require (maybe in `AppDelegate`)

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, 
                                                 with: .duckOthers)
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

Comment: Thank you, why i can't make the avplayer public to change properties instead of making a function?

Comment: @SwiftNewling You can if you want, no issues. I have used functions to enable finer control over the actions.

Comment: accessing the player from a viewController directly isn't good as i've tested now. It doesn't get proper valid information like if its playing. It tells me it's false but it plays really. If i write that func in my service it works fine

Comment: @SwiftNewling I changed my comments to be in context with my answer as I thought I may have misunderstood you

Comment: okay, can you check the question again i added something and want to know your opinion

Comment: @SwiftNewling It is generally a better idea to ask a new question than to update the current question with new/more cases. see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, keeping questions specific lets others take advantage of it's answers as well.

Comment: @SwiftNewling Besides, this new question you have, if you ask it separately, it may be closed for being "too broad" or "primarily opinion based". Because there's nothing wrong with it and different people will suggest different approaches

Comment: @SwiftNewling Personally, there are a few things I would do differently. For starters, read up on the SOLID principles. But one things that stands out that I would absolutely not do is, I would not put the `UISlider` handling logic in this class. Instead I would have a function that returns the `player`'s elapsed & total time. The `UISlider` logic would then go in a `viewController` or elsewhere, and handled there. This way if tomorrow you want to reuse the player class or change the `UIControl`, you don't have to modify the player class, you just handle it as per the control where it is used.

Comment: @SwiftNewling Then to handle the slider updates, you could provide a way to be notified on changes. Either through delegates or update handler closures. Whereas, to handle slider changes, you would provide the required functionality in the player to take updates like `func seekTo(timeInterval: TimeInterval)` and handle it internally. This way you would slowly create a player class that can be reused.

Comment: Ah okay. And what about the labels that I pass in an argument in setup player ?

Comment: @SwiftNewling I didn't see that. Well... you shouldn't. Same story as `UISlider`. I wouldn't let this class get dependent on other classes. To update the `label` periodically, or the `slider` for that matter, you should adopt a different pattern, like delegation or closures. You could keep the timer within the `player` class that simply calls the delegate(s)/closure(s). Then the `viewController` who has subscribed, will handle the update itself in it's own way, i.e. by updating it's `slider` and `label`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've updated the question again. It would be great if you could take a look :)

Comment: @SwiftNewling Just one minor (big) thing, I would make that `delegate` reference `weak` to avoid a retain cycle. i.e. `public weak var delegate: AVPlayerServiceDelegate?` But do note that currently only one `viewController` can be the `delegate`. If another `viewController` becomes the `delegate` then the previous `viewController` will stop updating. Maybe multicast delegation pattern could be a possible solution. In either case, the `delegate` references should be weak and even auto-removed when no longer in memory. Otherwise I think it's in decent condition now.

Comment: how can I auto remove it ?

Comment: @SwiftNewling I suggested auto-remove for multicast delegates because you would need an array of delegates for it. What you have right now doesn't need auto-remove, in a sense, it already is because of `weak`. All is well, happy coding :)